# Does TransactionScope have a limit on the depth of the call stack underneath it?

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I hope that title is intelligible.  Basically I'm wondering if, once you begin a TransactionScope, there is any limit to the number of nested calls you can make within it.  For example:

```
void Method1()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        Method2();
        scope.Complete();
    }

}

void Method2()
{
    Method3();
}

void Method3()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        // write stuff to DB
    }
}
```

Is there a level N such that if the SQL operations were in MethodN, there would be some sort of problem, such as not being able to rollback the SQL inserts, or never getting to those inserts in the first place?

Comment: Why would you assume that there was such a limit, and if there were, that is wasn't documented in big, bold letters in the documentation?

Comment: I'm not assuming.  I'm asking if there is one.  I didn't find evidence of this in documentation but wanted to see if anyone knew of any pitfalls.  One could argue our careers as developers are littered with trial by fire moments where we discover a pitfall that should seemingly have been documented in big, bold letters (but isn't).

Comment: Okay, but the two concepts `a transaction and its scope` on the one hand and `call hierarchy depth` on the other seem completely orthogonal to me - that's why I was asking if there was a specific reasoning behind the question.

Comment: I guess my main concern is that I might get into trouble if I try to do too much work within a TransactionScope.  I wondered if Microsoft had perhaps anticipated such troublesome design decisions and put things in place to curb them, such as call stack limits, timers, memory limits for objects in the scope, etc.  The feeling I'm getting from your comments is that no such limits exist and that I just need to be mindful in my design.